# How to copy multiple Actions to multiple objects?

Tags: python, keyframes, dopesheet

Iam trying to assign "ACTION1" and "ACTION2" to several objects.

This is my current code:

```
def copyAnim(animObj):
    context = bpy.context
    obj = bpy.data.objects[animObj]
    obs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.name.startswith("object")]
    action = obj.animation_data.action
    print(obs)

    for ob in obs:
        if ob.animation_data:
            ob.animation_data.action = action.copy()
        else:
            ob.animation_data_create()
            ob.animation_data.action = action.copy()

copyAnim('Object_Holding_ACTION1')
```

But here is the Problem: if i want to add another action (with
`copyAnim('Object_Holding_ACTION2')`
)
"ACTION1" gets overwritten.

Comment: Overwritten? each object with name starting with "object" will be assigned a copy of the action on the object named "Object_Holding_ACTION2"

Comment: Yea, thats my problem. I want "ACTION1" and "ACTION2" both to affect the objects.

Comment: Have a look at the NLA

Comment: I played around a bit with the NLA. It got almost all functionality i want, but i couldn't get overlapping animations to work. @batFINGER